# Getting error "Need Admin Approval" while calling PowerBI REST API

Tags: rest, powershell, powerbi, powershell-3.0

I want to extract dataset refresh history for the dataset. I am using the REST API in PowerShell script. I registered native app and provided all the permissions but getting error "Need admin approval".
What admin approval needed?

While running the above code getting the error

> Need admin approval
>
> needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an
>   admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app
>   before you can use it.
>
> Have an admin account? Sign in with that account Return to the
>   application without granting consent" Note: I am not the admin of my
>   cloud

Please help me what needs to be done to resolve this error. Also what approval is required and how can my admin provide the access?

```bsh
$clientId = "NativeAppClientId"

# Calls the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) to authenticate against AAD
function GetAuthToken {
    if (-not (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile)) {
        Import-Module AzureRm.Profile
    }

    $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" 
    $resourceAppIdURI = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize";
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Auto")
    return $authResult
}

# Get the auth token from AAD
$token = GetAuthToken
# Building Rest API header with authorization token
$authHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = $token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
}
# properly format groups path
$groupsPath = ""
if ($groupID -eq "me") {
    $groupsPath = "myorg"
} else {
    $groupsPath = "myorg/groups/$groupID"
}

# Check the refresh history
$uri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/$groupsPath/datasets/$datasetID/refreshes"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authHeader -Method GET -Verbose
```

Comment: Just _ask an admin to grant permission to this app_. They **should know**  _what admin approval needed_ and how-to _provide the access_ (if any).

Comment: @JosefZ Could you please let me know what access is required